# Attach console to LaunchConfiguration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a plugin which implements the `ILaunchConfigurationDelegate`.

I have to override this method: `launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode, ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor);`

Can I attach a `TextConsole` to it like for the ones in the `JavaApplication` launch type when writing with `System.out.println()`?

I would like to have that in order that my launch has the same lifecycle management for its console.

Essentially my `ILaunchConfiguration` type is a container which holds all possible other `ILaunchConfiguration` types. When launching my launch container I want to log the behaviour of the others which start in a sequence. This logging would be ideal in a TextConsole. Example: 'Hello World started.' 'Hello World terminated', 'Pi approximator started' ... etc.

Comment: Are you aware that Eclipse has _Launch Groups_  (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/M4/) since Oxygen M4?

Comment: Just to clarify: each contained launch would have its own console, plus the launch container would have a console on its own.Right?

Comment: Yes I am, but my implementation offers a few additions to it.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly.

Comment: What is the added value of a console that contains log messages of what the container launch does? Wouldn't it be sufficient if the launcher would let the user know if something goes wrong instead of chatting _uninteresting_  information of what it currently does?

Comment: If you think your additions are be of general use, you may consider opening an enhancement request to include your additions into the platform.

Comment: The console should function as a logger for the waiting conditions in order to let a developer see that for instance a launch is waiting for termination, before launching the next one etc. There can be many use-cases where this type of logging can be useful. I will think of an enhancement request to the platform. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no extra steps necessary to redirect std in/out to the Eclipse console. The *Common* tab of every launch configuration type has an *Allocate console* option that provides this feature if enabled.

[image]

If your launch configuration type does not provide the `CommonTab`, you can set the `IDebugUIConstants.ATTR_CAPTURE_IN_CONSOLE` attribute of your `ILaunchConfiguration` to `true`.

For the container launch, you can simply allocate a `TextConsole` to write the log messages to. The debug/launch framework attaches consoles to `IProcess` instances and this won't help here but you may want to look to `ProcessConsole` and `ProcessConsoleManager` to adopt the relevant part to opening and discarding the console.

Alternatively, you could investigate if setting the `ATTR_CAPTURE_IN_CONSOLE` of the container launch to true and creating a dummy `IProcess` that satisfies the requirements of the `ProcessConsoleManager` wrt to consoles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was a bit superficial with the question I posted. I've updated it just now.